# Dual of locally free sheaves commute with direct sums?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

For any locally free sheaf $\mathcal  F$ on a scheme $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ of finite rank, its dual is defined as  $\mathcal F^{\vee}:=\mathscr Hom(\mathcal F,\mathcal O_X)$. So,

> if $\mathcal F,\mathcal G$ are locally free sheaves, what is the dual of $\mathcal F\oplus\mathcal G$?

I would like to think that $(\mathcal F\oplus\mathcal G)^{\vee}=\mathcal F^{\vee}\oplus\mathcal G^{\vee}$, since for every short exact sequence of locally free
sheaves on $X$ the $\mathscr Hom(-,\mathcal O_X)$ functor is exact, but I think that this is not true because short exact sequences of locally free sheaves don't necessarily split, (see this answer: [Short exact sequence of vector bundles vs locally free sheaves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2390831/short-exact-sequence-of-vector-bundles-vs-locally-free-sheaves)).

> In the particular if $X$ is a projective variety, what is the dual of $\mathcal O(1)\oplus\mathcal O(2)$ ?

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: The formula $(F \oplus G)^\vee \cong F^\vee \oplus G^\vee$ is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any additive functor between abelian categories sends split exact sequences to split exact sequences. For example you can see a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264401/additive-functor-over-a-short-split-exact-sequence) for abelian groups. Since $^{\vee}$ is an additive functor, it sends the split sequence

$0 \to \mathcal F \to \mathcal F \oplus \mathcal G \to \mathcal G \to 0$

to

$0 \to \mathcal G^{\vee} \to \mathcal (F \oplus \mathcal G)^{\vee} \to \mathcal F^{\vee} \to 0$.

and since this is again split, $(F \oplus \mathcal G)^{\vee} \cong F^\vee \oplus \mathcal G^{\vee}$. Note that this applieas to $\mathcal O_X$-modules in general, not only locally free sheaves, and to any other functor of $\mathcal O_X$-modules which is additive (almost all of them are)